# How do I calculate the standard error of Kalman Filter parameter estimates?

Tags: time-series, python, standard-error, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I am trying to implement the Schwartz-Smith (2000) commodity pricing model from the paper [*Short-term variations and long-term dynamics in commodity prices*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2661607.pdf?casa_token=cJE8xBT2xhsAAAAA:ctIUoAiO9MmnyS90cu29CpPyZa0_rIsMQneJz1z5DML1tc5WHdl0FfyVNKPAzhLZAZKleSD0mi4Ss9HO5HjVvADxH8Eq5YjDQfTnf_fn0lEa62ZGS-Cm)

The model is estimated using the Kalman Filter, where the state space is described by the following two equations:

***x**<sub>t</sub> = **c** + **Gx**<sub>t-1</sub> + $\omega$<sub>t</sub>* 
***y**<sub>t</sub> = **d**<sub>t</sub> + **F**<sub>t</sub>**x**<sub>t</sub> + **v**<sub>t</sub>*,

where ***x**<sub>t</sub>* = [$\chi$<sub>t</sub>, $\xi$<sub>t</sub>] is a 2 x 1 vector of the state space variables and ***y**<sub>t</sub>* = [*lnF<sub>T1</sub>, . . . , lnF<sub>Tn</sub>*] is an *n* x 1 vector of of the log futures prices at time *t* with maturities *T<sub>i</sub>* for *i = 1, . . . , n*
***c***, ***G***, ***d***, and ***F*** are the state space parameters with appropriate dimensions
$\omega$<sub>t</sub> is a 2 x 1 vector of disturbances with E[$\omega$<sub>t</sub>] = ***0*** and a covariance matrix of Var[$\omega$<sub>t</sub>] = ***W***
**v**<sub>t</sub> is an n x 1 vector of disturbances with E[**v**<sub>t</sub>] = ***0*** and  a covariance matrix of Var[**v**<sub>t</sub>] = ***V***

All of the state space parameters with the exception of ***V***, so ***c***, ***G***, ***W***, ***d***, and ***F*** are functions of seven underlying constant parameters (as well as the time increments and the maturities):

$\theta$ = ($\kappa$, $\sigma$<sub>$\chi$</sub>, $\mu$<sub>$\xi$</sub>, $\sigma$<sub>$\xi$</sub>, $\rho$ <sub>$\xi$$\chi$</sub>, $\lambda$<sub>$\chi$</sub>, $\mu$<sub>$\xi$</sub><sup>*</sup>)

The nature of which is described in the paper.

While ***V*** is assumed to be a diagonal matrix, whose elements are *s<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>* for *i = 1, . . . , n*

I am trying to estimate these parameters with the Expectation-Maximization (EM) algorithm. For that I am using the *pykalman* Python package to calculate the loglikelihood of the observations, then maximize the loglikelihood with respect to $\theta$ and the elements of ***V***, using *scipy.optimize*. I then reestimate the Kalman Filter with the new parameter estimates; this is repeated until convergence.

The problem with this approach is that I am only getting the end result of the estimation and no descriptive statistics. In the original paper, next to the estimated parameter values, the standard errors are also provided but the method with which they are calculated is not described. How can I go about obtaining the values of these standard errors?

Comment: I’m not aware of any way to extract standard errors using EM. Maybe there is, but if you switch to MLE using the likelihood and optimize using a general purpose solver, you can extract the hessian from the output.